# Replace object and keep existing pointers to this Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, reference

I cannot find a way to replace an object without losing the linked pointers in javascript.

In my scenario, I create some Object

```
var a = new someObject();
selectedbyUser.push(a);
objectWithissues.push(a);
objectBeingreviewed.push(a);
...
```

Now at some point I'd like to replace this object with another (like pointers in C++)

I could rewrite the entire object with the arguments of the other object, but I'd prefer to replace it:

```
a = new someObject();
```

now this only detaches a from the current object to make it point to the new object, What I want, is to replace the object with the new object, so that the references inside the arrays point to this new object.. Is this possible?

Comment: If the object doesn't have any non-deletable properties on it, you could delete them all, then use `Object.assign`. But this is *really really weird* to do. You might consider pushing a wrapper instead of pushing `a`, and then have the *wrapper* change itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do what you are asking, but most of them require changing the signature of the functions.

One way to do it is to create a getter function for that object, and pass that function instead of the object itself.

```js
var a = 5;

function getA() {
  return a;
}

function test(getObj) {
  console.log(getObj());
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(getObj());
  }, 250);
}

test(getA);

a = 2;
```

Another way would be to wrap the object with another object, make all functions keep a reference to the parent Object and whenever you change the reference, there won't be any other references to that object left.

```js
var wrapper = {
  a: 5
};

function test(wrap) {
  console.log(wrap.a);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(wrap.a);
  }, 250);
}

test(wrapper);

wrapper.a = 2;
```

Finally, If you don't need the reference to the original object you can just replace all of the fields, instead of creating a new object (assuming there are no private fields).

Answer (score 1):

You should not reassign to `a`, otherwise you will assign a new object reference to `a`, but you can replace the object `a` is pointing to with `Object.assign()`:

```js
class A {
  constructor(val) {
    this.b = val;
  }
  
  sayHi() {
    console.log('val is', this.b);
  }
}

const arr = [];

const a = new A(1);
arr.push(a);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
arr[0].sayHi();

Object.assign(a, new A(2));

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
arr[0].sayHi();
```